# Question on parallel resonance

Tags: parallel, resonance

[image: I cant interpret what this question]

I cant interpret what this question means. Can anyone help me answer it. Thanks in advance

Comment: If \$I_R\$, \$I_C\$ and \$I_L\$ are the current phasors, then I see two correct answers to this exercice (B and D)!

Comment: They haven't said that the current source is sinusoidal and at the resonant frequency. If there is only one correct answer then because (B) and (D) say the same thing (at resonance) they can be ruled out. This leaves (A) and (B) but at resonance (i.e. has settled down) Ir must be 1mA - this rules out (A) and (B) which means what?

Comment: Actually if L is not an ideal inductor also (A) is true. Then (A), (B) and (D) are true. Maybe the question was to find the wrong answer.

Comment: Which "question" are you referring to? Don`t you have the complete task to be solved?

Comment: What does \$|\cdot|\$ mean here? At resonance the current through the resistor will be 1 mA RMS.

Answer (score 1):

It means they want you to decide which of the four possible answers (A, B, C, or D) is true, keeping in mind that the impedance of a parallel resonant LC is:

A. High

B. Low